# Oozie workflow file cannot see start step, error E0701

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am running an Oozie job with a workflow.xml file which begins:

```
<!-- <workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1"> -->

<start to="imagesCreateSequenceFile"/>  

<action name="imagesCreateSequenceFile">
<map-reduce>
 <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
     <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'start'.
```

I am pretty sure my job is pointing to the correct workflow.xml file on hdfs (so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648624/e0701-xml-schema-error-in-oozie-workflow) does not fix it).

Any help is appreciated in working out why my job cannot see 'start'.
TIA!

PS I have tried a different workflow.xml and it gives the same error.

Comment: Have you ran `oozie validate workflow.xml`?  That will give you a little more insight into why it's failing before you put everything up on HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the comment marks around the first line, i.e. make it:

```
<workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
```